# webpack: require() from within a ES6 constructor -

Tags: dependencies, ecmascript-6, webpack, require

I have a dynamic JSON file generated using `module.exports`

**A.js**

```
module.exports = {
  regexes: [
    /aaa/,
    /bbb/
  ]
}
```

This works fine when I do this:

**B.js**

```
var config = require('./A');
```

But now I have this scenario where the path is unknown and passed as a parameter to an ES6 class. So i tried:

```
class B {
  constructor( private dir: string ) {
     const configpath = path.join(dir, 'serverConfig.js');
     const config = require(`${configpath}`);
  }
}
```

I get the errors

`Critical dependencies: the request of a dependency is an expression`

and

`Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed`

It gets compiled by webpack like that

```
 var configpath = path.join(this.configDir, 'serverConfig.js');
 this.serverConfig = __webpack_require__(24)("" + configpath);
```

This should be working , as this plain es5 code shows:

```
var A = function() {
  var name = 'util';
  var util = require(name);
}

a = new A();
```

I am not sure what I do wrong here. Is there a webpack configuration to change?

Also, when I actually run the code (because this is just a warning), I get this error :

`Error: Cannot find module '[correctPath]/serverConfig.js'.`

Where [correctPath] is indeed a shorcut for visibility.

Comment: Why not require the config before creating `B` and pass in the whole config? The problem is that because your `require` is dynamic, Webpack has no way of knowing what file it references, and thus no way to bundle up that file in the final application. Dynamic `require` calls are a bad idea.

Comment: I just realized that earlier that webpack needs static requires. I went trough a lot of pain to get this info, also it seem slike Webpack2 will support System.import for dynamic loading of modules. I finally ended up going back to `tsc` which does almost the same job for my scenario ( a pure node.js module )